# Python Tkinter GUI scrambled

Tags: python, user-interface, widget, tkinter

I'm trying to create a GUI for a simple numerical estimation of differential equation solution, but the layout doesn't work as intended (I've tried pack and grid). This is my first GUI and maybe I'm missing something simple. Thanks in advance.

Regards,

Piotr

```
from Tkinter import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class Application(Frame):
    def run_brussel(self):
        t_start = float(self.t_start_entry.get())
        t_end = float(self.t_end_entry.get())
        t_diff = float(self.t_diff_entry.get())
        k1 = float(self.k1_entry.get())
        k2 = float(self.k2_entry.get())
        k3 = float(self.k3_entry.get())
        k4 = float(self.k4_entry.get())
        A = float(self.A_entry.get())
        B = float(self.B_entry.get())
        X = float(self.X_entry.get())
        Y = float(self.Y_entry.get())
        mode = self.mode.get()

        brussel = brussel_func(t_start, t_end, t_diff, k1, k2, k3, k4, A, B, X, Y)
        plot_brussel(mode, brussel[0], brussel[1], brussel[2])

    def createWidgets(self):
        self.t_start_label = Label(text="start time")
        self.t_start_label.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W)
        self.t_start_entry = Entry(self)
        self.t_start_entry.delete(0, END)
        self.t_start_entry.insert(0, "0.0")
        self.t_start_entry.grid(row=0, column=1)

        self.t_end_label = Label(text="end time")
        self.t_end_label.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W)
        self.t_end_entry = Entry(self)
        self.t_end_entry.delete(0, END)
        self.t_end_entry.insert(0, "100.0")
        self.t_end_entry.grid(row=1, column=1)

        self.t_diff_label = Label(text="time precision")
        self.t_diff_label.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=W)
        self.t_diff_entry = Entry(self)
        self.t_diff_entry.delete(0, END)
        self.t_diff_entry.insert(0, "0.0001")
        self.t_diff_entry.grid(row=2, column=1)

        self.k1_label = Label(text="k1 value")
        self.k1_label.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky=W)
        self.k1_entry = Entry(self)
        self.k1_entry.delete(0, END)
        self.k1_entry.insert(0, "1.0")
        self.k1_entry.grid(row=3, column=1)

        self.k2_label = Label(text="k2 value")
        self.k2_label.grid(row=4, column=0, sticky=W)
        self.k2_entry = Entry(self)
        self.k2_entry.delete(0, END)
        self.k2_entry.insert(0, "1.0")
        self.k2_entry.grid(row=4, column=1)

        self.k3_label = Label(text="k3 value")
        self.k3_label.grid(row=5, column=0, sticky=W)
        self.k3_entry = Entry(self)
        self.k3_entry.delete(0, END)
        self.k3_entry.insert(0, "1.0")
        self.k3_entry.grid(row=5, column=1)

        self.k4_label = Label(text="k4 value")
        self.k4_label.grid(row=6, column=0, sticky=W)
        self.k4_entry = Entry(self)
        self.k4_entry.delete(0, END)
        self.k4_entry.insert(0, "1.0")
        self.k4_entry.grid(row=6, column=1)

        self.A_label = Label(text="initial A concentr.")
        self.A_label.grid(row=7, column=0, sticky=W)
        self.A_entry = Entry(self)
        self.A_entry.delete(0, END)
        self.A_entry.insert(0, "1.0")
        self.A_entry.grid(row=7, column=1)

        self.B_label = Label(text="initial B concentr.")
        self.B_label.grid(row=8, column=0, sticky=W)
        self.B_entry = Entry(self)
        self.B_entry.delete(0, END)
        self.B_entry.insert(0, "2.5")
        self.B_entry.grid(row=8, column=1)

        self.X_label = Label(text="initial X concentr.")
        self.X_label.grid(row=9, column=0, sticky=W)
        self.X_entry = Entry(self)
        self.X_entry.delete(0, END)
        self.X_entry.insert(0, "0.0")
        self.X_entry.grid(row=9, column=1)

        self.Y_label = Label(text="initial Y concentr.")
        self.Y_label.grid(row=10, column=0, sticky=W)
        self.Y_entry = Entry(self)
        self.Y_entry.delete(0, END)
        self.Y_entry.insert(0, "0.0")
        self.Y_entry.grid(row=10, column=1)

        self.mode = IntVar()
        self.modus_operandi_label = Label(text="plot type")
        self.modus_operandi_label.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky=W)
        self.modus_operandi_button = Radiobutton(self, text="X : Y", variable=self.mode, value=True).grid(row=1, column=2, sticky=W)
        self.modus_operandi_button = Radiobutton(self, text="X, Y : time", variable=self.mode, value=False).grid(row=2, column=2, sticky=W)

        self.plot = Button(self)
        self.plot["text"] = "PLOT",
        self.plot["command"] = self.run_brussel
        self.plot.grid(row=1, column=3)

        self.QUIT = Button(self)
        self.QUIT["text"] = "QUIT"
        self.QUIT["fg"]   = "red"
        self.QUIT["command"] =  self.quit
        self.QUIT.grid(row=0, column=3)

    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.grid()
        self.createWidgets()

def brussel_func(t_start, t_end, t_diff, k1, k2, k3, k4, A, B, X, Y):
    t = t_start
    t_list = []
    t_list.append(0)
    X_list = [X]
    Y_list = [Y]
    step = 0

    while t < t_end:
        X_diff = t_diff * (k1 * A - k2 * B * X_list[step] + k3 * X_list[step]**2 *             Y_list[step] - k4 * X_list[step])
        Y_diff = t_diff * (k2 * B * X_list[step] - k3 * X_list[step]**2 * Y_list[step])
        X_list.append(X)
        Y_list.append(Y)
        t_list.append(t)
        t += t_diff
        X += X_diff
        Y += Y_diff
        step += 1

    return [t_list, X_list, Y_list]

def plot_brussel(mode, t_list, X_list, Y_list):
    p = []

    #plots X : Y    
    if mode == True:
            p = plt.plot(X_list, Y_list)
            plt.xlabel('x')
            plt.ylabel('y')

    #plots X, Y : time
    else:
            p = plt.plot(t_list, X_list, label="X")
            p += plt.plot(t_list, Y_list, label="Y")
            plt.legend(loc="upper left", bbox_to_anchor=(1,1))
            plt.xlabel('time')

    #displays chosen plot
    plt.show(p)

def main():
    root = Tk()
    root.wm_title("Brusselator")
    app = Application(master=root)
    app.mainloop()
    root.destroy()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: And what, exactly, are you intending? You aren't giving any row or column information to the calls to `grid`, so I'm not sure what you're expecting it to do. Also, I can't tell what your code does because it has indentation errors (see the line immediately after the line `while t < t_end`). It also includes some useless import statements. Please make an effort to provide code that actually illustrates the problem you're having.

Comment: Fixed the indentation error (it's late and I use tabulation, not spaces - had to change it by hand). The version I posted is without row and column information (I was testing it). I used first column for entry labels, second column for entries, third column for radiobutton label and radiobuttons and fourth column for quit and plot buttons. Python displays it in this order: entries, radiobuttons, buttons, labels. That's obviously incorrect.

Comment: Ok, well the correct way to specify the locations of your widgets is with the `row` and `column` attributes of the `grid` method, so why don't you post the code where you do that and we can help you debug from there?

Comment: Ok, I edited the code to include the column and row information. Take a look, please. I had to take some rest, it was 5 AM when I was posting it.

Comment: Here's code so you can copy/paste it: http://pastebin.com/qRJRWKcT

Comment: Also, I've noticed that pressing the plot button multiple times leads to MemoryError. Memory doesn't clear itself. How do I fix this? Is there a simple solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you forgot to give your Labels a root widget.  Honestly I'm surprised they  showed up at all - I think they must have defaulted to the active Tk instance, so they got gridded outside the frame.

Anyhow, the fix is easy - add `self` as the first argument of all your Labels.

I.e. wherever you wrote something like this:

```
self.t_start_label = Label(text="start time")
```

instead write this:

```
self.t_start_label = Label(self, text="start time")
                           ^^^^
```

The Labels then appear next to the Entries.

One style note - I recommend that you move all your `Widget.grid` calls to one place in your code - makes it much easier to read, understand, and change the grid layout.

Comment: Hi, thanks. Could you take a look at the last problem with this script? It seems that matplotlib doesn't release memory properly: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18256233/python-matplotlib-memory-clog-not-clearing

Comment: @user2126752 Sure, I'll take a look at it.  If this answer solved your problem, please mark it as "accepted" by clicking the little checkmark so future users know that it worked for you, and this site becomes more useful.